# how to pass a password with a cron job safely?

Tags: cron, password, authentication, curl

I have a site map generator script placed in this URL

```
http://www.mydomain.com/admin/sitemapgen/
```

However this URL is protected with an username and a password in auth_type basic method.

I need to place a cron to access this URL once a week.
So I've decided to use the `curl` command and placed the cron like below.

```
curl -u username:mypassword http://www.mydomain.com/admin/sitemapgen/
```

I'm aware that sending a password through http is insecure, however at least I'm trying to hide the password from server/hosting panel users from this `curl` command.

1) Are there any methods to hide the password in this `curl` command? I read something about placing a plain text file with the password in server and use it with the -k option. However I'm not in to place the password in a plain text file either.

2) Are there any other commands than curl to use for this specific purpose?

Comment: Why can't you try hashing the password and pass that hash code as password in your `curl` command?.I don't know what limitations you have but it's just an another way to hide the password.

Comment: @Thushi this username and password is handling by Apache web server. If I md5 the password, I believe the Apache wouldn't recognize it, would it?

Comment: I don't know about Apache will recognize it or not but I heard something about `htpasswd` may be you can try that.

Comment: @Thushi htpasswd is a command to create and store user password. As per my experience, its not helpful for my requirement.

Comment: Comment:  You are using plain text http:// thus any cute way of obscuring your password on the command line will only make it easily visible during the network transaction.

Comment: @mdpc I'm aware about the security risk of transfering the password via plain http. As I described, my requirement is to hide the password from ordinary system users who can easily see it through command line, cPanel or the running cron commands using `ps` command.

Answer (score 7):

To avoid showing the password on the command where other users can see it with `ps`, you should not pass the password in the command. It's why many utilities don't support passwords as command line arguments.

Instead store your password in a `~/.netrc` file and pass the `-n` option to curl.

For the details of file syntax, I let you see the man of curl.

Comment: This answer is useful and I've already tried it and working.
However when creating the .netrc file I had to specify the `machine` name. And according to above my example, I have specified the value as www.mydomain.com
My requirement is done. However another security vulnerability occurs. Because I don't want to let some one access the main domain. However after creating .netrc file, now every one can `curl -n` in the site without any username and password. is there any method to specify the .netrc machine name to www.mydomain.com/admin/sitemapgen/

Comment: You should make this action using a custom user for the generation